# Facebook found a way to fix mobile scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I've been trying to change a div from relative to fixed after the window scrolls to a certain distance. It works fine on desktops, but mobile browsers don't fire events until after the scrolling has finished. Facebook found a way to fix this. There's plenty of answers on Stack Exchange saying what they're doing is impossible.

So I want to look at their javascript and see how they did it. The only problem is there's a TON of code. How would I find out the code they're using for a certain nav bar? Is there any way to use Chrome's dev tools to inspect the javascript applied to a div?

Edit: I'm not completely convinced Facebook fixed it. I was scrolling slowly and it worked. But if you flick the page, it still disappears and then reappears as soon as the scrolling stops. Not sure if Facebook did anything different here. Sorry to get anyone's hopes up.

Comment: If you want to see what I'm talking about, go to facebook.com on a mobile phone. Go to an event. There's a nav bar that says "Join" "Maybe" "Decline" and "...". Try scrolling down and you'll see it automatically scrolls with the page. Magic!

Comment: "javascript applied to a div" makes no sense to me.

Comment: Right, I was being unclear. There's some javascript that changes the div from relative to fixed. For some special reason, it's working on mobile correctly. But it only works on Facebook.com and not for my website or anyone else who has the same bug. So I want to know which section of their code is acting on the div. That's the section of code I want to use for my own website.

Comment: They could be using a virtual scroll that handles scrolling outside of the native scroller. Basically think of it as a touch event that changes the transform-y position on touch move, but prevents default on each of the touch events.

Comment: Chrome's dev tools let you set DOM breakpoints (e.g. attribute modification.)

Answer (score 1):

If you go to:
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yb/r/-y0w_6fw9Tx.js

and search for the code: j.getScrollTop()

then you will get this:

```
k.listen('scroll', null, q.bind(this));

function q() {
    var s = i.getPos(n),
        t = j.getScrollTop();
    if (t > s.y) {
        h.addClass(m, "_5d4y");
    } else h.removeClass(m, "_5d4y");
}
```

Which converted to non facebook code would be:

```
var nav = document.getElementById('nav'),
    offset = nav.getBoundingClientRect().top;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > offset) {
        nav.className = 'nav fixed';
    } else {
        nav.className = 'nav';
    }
});
```

I've created a jsfiddle which shows it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/CHK96/1/

Comment: Doesn't work on mobile.

Comment: It works on Android with Chrome if you lock the viewport scaling e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/CHK96/2/

Comment: With a little more work (and some jQuery) I've got it to work on Firefox as well: http://jsfiddle.net/CHK96/5/

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS, doesn't work on mobile.